# TextInputLayout is overwriting TextInputEditText

Tags: android, xml

This is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerFreq"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/start_freq_text"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextStartFreq"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/start_freq_edit_text"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/end_freq_text"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextEndFreq"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/end_freq_edit_text"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/length_seconds_text"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextLength"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/length_seconds_edit_text"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/min_freq_text"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextMinFreq"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/min_freq_edit_text"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/max_freq_text"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextMaxFreq"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/max_freq_edit_text"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried using a ConstraintLayout before the LinearLayout and the top TextInputLayout was rendered correctly. The ones below it are exactly the same, so I am not sure why they aren't working.

It's an issue with the TextInputLayout hint not moving up until the TextInputLayout gets tapped. Is there a way to get it to stay up top?

Is there a attribute I need to set or a certain way I need to lay them out? The documentation on the Material io page doesn't have a layout example on the text field page. https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-fields

Comment: What is the problem ? it's not working with constraint layout ? but you post the linearlayout implementation ..

Comment: My bad; I meant the I used a ConstraintLayout first and then tried it with a LinearLayout thinking it might make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Remove** the hint from `TextInputEditText` and use the `app:placeholderText` in the `TextInputLayout`:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:hint="Label"
        app:placeholderText="Placeholder Text"
```

[image]

**Note:** it requires at least the version `1.2.0-alpha03`.

Comment: That kind of worked. The problem is I want the placeholder to always be over the text field instead of only when the text field has focus.

Comment: @JohnGlen Currently it is the standard behavior. The label (hint) is collapsed only on focus or when the field has text. There is a [request](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/810) and a 2 PRs to support it: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/pull/1028 and https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/pull/1163

Comment: The page I linked makes it look like it is possible with the first image. Kind of misleading. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Also, thank you for linking the bug page with the solution.